# Override Style on Polymer extended element

Tags: polymer

Im trying to override the styling when an element is selected.

This works on Safari and Firefox. It does not work on Chrome 38.

```
<link rel="import" href="../polymer/polymer.html">
<link rel="import" href="../core-selector/core-selector.html">

<polymer-element name="my-selector" extends="core-selector"> 

  <template>
    <style>
    :host::shadow .item.core-selected{
      background: blue;
    } 
    </style>

    <shadow></shadow> 
  </template>

  <script>
    Polymer('my-selector');
  </script>
</polymer-element>
```

Example:

```
<my-selector>
  <div class="item">Item 1</div>
  <div class="item">Item 2</div>
  <div class="item">Item 3</div>
</my-selector>
```

Answer (score 3):

Try:

```
::content .item.core-selected {
  ...
}
```

`:host::shadow` try to picks elements out of the host's shadow dom. In this case, this is not where the elements are. The `<div class="item">` elements are still going through an insertion point and are part of light dom. They need to be styled with `::content`.

```html
<script src="http://www.polymer-project.org/platform.js"></script>
<link rel="import" href="http://www.polymer-project.org/components/core-selector/core-selector.html">


<polymer-element name="my-selector" extends="core-selector">
  <template>
    <style>
      ::content .item.core-selected {
        background: blue;
        color: white;
      }
    </style>
    <shadow></shadow>
  </template>
  <script>
    Polymer('my-selector');
  </script>
</polymer-element>

<my-selector selected="0">
  <div class="item">Item 1</div>
  <div class="item">Item 2</div>
  <div class="item">Item 3</div>
</my-selector>
```

Comment: Thank Eric! I guess when I saw it working on other browsers it confused me. I know polyfills work around creates a different selector. This works! Thanks!